# How to style exported excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I export an excel file just like it is showed in the railscasts video

http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel?view=asciicast

but I want backgroud color of alternate rows to be red and blue. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The gem they use in that screencast is mainly for making csv files.  It has some code for basic formatting just to make the data into an xls instead of a csv, but it's not set up to easily allow advanced formatting like color, borders etc.

If you want to do advanced formatting i'd recommend you use a different gem, such as Spreadsheet - https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet